# Are SOAP based web services meant to be used only with non-browser based applications?

Tags: web-development, http, browsers, web-services, restful

From what I have understood from browsing internet, SOAP is an application level protocol. If this is the case, then can I safely assume that all that happens thru/over browser (which uses HTTP application protocol) is NOT SOAP based web service and is most likely RESTful service. Also, does it mean that SOAP comes into  picture only for non-browser based web applications?.

**Addition:** So my further research tells me that SOAP is application layer protocol which can be (and mostly is) implemented over another application layer protocol http (It hadn't struck me earlier that one application layer can be implemented over another application layer. I had a strict 7 layer OSI model in mind). So even browser based applications can use SOAP protocol. Please correct me, if I am wrong here.