# who defines SOAP protocol?

Tags: web-development, http, browsers, web-services

A further follow up of my earlier question:

[Are SOAP based web services meant to be used only with non-browser based applications?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125293/are-soap-based-web-services-meant-to-be-used-only-with-non-browser-based-applica)

so I understand that SOAP is an application layer messaging protocol(typically implemented over HTTP). I want to understand who defines SOAP protocol. Is there some standard for it or the specific application/web service defines its own protocol and thus only client and server understands that particular SOAP protocol.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Wikipedia has some information, however it is not fully clear. It will certainly help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP Check out the History section. Here you will see that SOAP had quite a past. It appears that SOAP is not a standard at this point. However, you can see the different submissions to different organizations and at least read those submissions.